# Enable Users Script

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to make a script that will check a variety of settings and ask permission before changing them. I'm writing this for non-IT users, so each of the user checks is a pop out message box. I thought that this part of the code was working, but now not so much. I'm getting an error indicating the user wasn't found, but that's what I'm trying to use as an if-else trigger. [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef77I.png)

As always, thanks to all the saints out there saving my behind from this.

PS: I know its not overly secure to have the password hard coded into the script, and if it were up to me, we wouldn't do it this way. But this is how the boss wants it for now.

```
#User Group
If (Get-LocalGroup -Name "Koko Svc"){
    Write-Host "User Group Koko Svc already exists"
    }
    Else{
        $UserConfirm=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to create the Local Group `"Koko Svc`"?","`"Koko Svc`" Group Not Found",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNoCancel) 
        switch ($UserConfirm){
            "Yes" {
                    write-host "User agreed to create `"Koko Svc`""
                New-LocalGroup -Name 'Koko Svc' -Description 'KoKo Svc'
                    } 
                "No" {
                    write-host "User declined to create `"Koko Svc`""
                break
                    } 
                "Cancel" {
                    write-host "User stopped Settings Check"
                    exit
                    }
        }
    }
#Users
If (Get-LocalUser -Name "KoKo Svc"){
    Write-Host "User Koko Svc already exists"
    }
Else{
    $UserConfirm=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to create the User `"Koko Svc`"?","`"Koko Svc`" User Not Found",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNoCancel)
    switch ($UserConfirm){
    "Yes" {
            write-host "User agreed to create `"Koko Svc`""
        $Password1 = ConvertTo-SecureString "FooBar" -AsPlainText -Force
        New-LocalUser "KoKo Svc" -Password $Password1 -FullName "KoKo Svc"
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member ('KoKo Svc','Administrators')
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Koko Svc' -Member ('KoKo Svc','KoKo Svc')
        } 
        "No" {
            write-host "User declined to create `"Koko Svc`""
        break
        } 
        "Cancel" {
            write-host "User stopped Settings Check"
            exit
            }
    }
}

If (Get-LocalUser -Name "Valued Customer"){
    Write-Host "User Valued Customer already exists"
    }
Else{
    $UserConfirm=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to create the User `"Valued Customer`"?","`"Valued Customer`" User Not Found",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNoCancel)
    switch ($UserConfirm){
    "Yes" {
        write-host "User agreed to create `"Valued Customer`""
        $Password2 = ConvertTo-SecureString "BarFoo" -AsPlainText -Force
        New-LocalUser "Valued Customer" -Password $Password2 -FullName "Valued Customer"
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member ('Valued Customer','Administrators')
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Koko Svc' -Member ('Valued Customer','KoKo Svc')
        } 
        "No" {
            write-host "User declined to create `"Valued Customer`""
        break
        } 
        "Cancel" {
            write-host "User stopped Settings Check"
            exit
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could change it to

```
If (Get-LocalUser -Name "Valued Customer" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host User Valued Customer already exists
}
Else{
    write-host available
}
```

That way only if it produces an output it will run the if portion.

Comment: That's a very simple and elegant answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

A few things.

You can't use the same name for both a group and a user, which is why you get the error
`The name KoKo Svc is already in use`

On commands that you expect to fail, and want to take action if it does, use try/catch blocks. You can go the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` route, but in my opinion, that's sloppy and inelegant. You'll just be ignoring the error, instead of taking action on it. I would do something like this

```
    try
    {
        Get-LocalUser -Name $Name -ErrorAction Stop
        $exists = $true
        Write-Host "User $Name already exists"
    }
    catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UserNotFoundException]
    {
        $exists = $false
    }
```

then DRY the code up by tossing it in a simple function or two, so I'm not copy pasting a big chunk every time

```
function Test-LocalUser([string]$Name)
{
   try
    {
        Get-LocalUser -Name $Name -ErrorAction Stop
        $exists = $true
        Write-Host "User $Name already exists"
    }
    catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UserNotFoundException]
    {
        $exists = $false
    }
    return $exists
}
function Test-LocalGroup([string]$Name)
{
    try
    {
        Get-LocalGroup -Name $Name -ErrorAction Stop
        $exists = $true
        Write-Host "Group $Name already exists"
    }
    catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupNotFoundException]
    {
        $exists = $false
    }
    return $exists
}
```

Then for your code, you can do something like this

```
$group = "Koko Svc group"
if(!(Test-LocalGroup -Name $group))
{
    $UserConfirm=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to create the Local Group `"$group`"?","`"$group`" Group Not Found",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNoCancel) 
    switch ($UserConfirm)
    {
        "Yes" 
        {
            write-host "User agreed to create `"$group`""
            New-LocalGroup -Name $group -Description $group
        } 
        "No" 
        {
            write-host "User declined to create `"$group`""
            break
        } 
        "Cancel" 
        {
            write-host "User stopped Settings Check"
            exit
        }
    }
}
#Users

$user = "Koko Svc user"

if(!(Test-LocalUser -Name "Koko Svc"))
{
    $UserConfirm=[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to create the User `"$user`"?","`"$user`" User Not Found",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNoCancel)
    switch ($UserConfirm)
    {
        "Yes" 
        {
            write-host "User agreed to create `"$user`""
            $Password1 = ConvertTo-SecureString "FooBarasdasdasdasdadad2334342342!!!" -AsPlainText -Force
            New-LocalUser "$user" -Password $Password1 -FullName "$user"
            Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member ($user,'Administrators')
            Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $group -Member ($user,$group)
        } 
        "No" 
        {
            write-host "User declined to create `"$user`""
            break
        } 
        "Cancel" 
        {
            write-host "User stopped Settings Check"
            exit
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend tossing the user creation portion into a function as well, to reduce all the copy-paste code. If this is something designed for other people, making it easy to maintain is a priority. By making functions out of your repeated code, you only have to make a change in one place, rather than every copy/pasted section. If you want to see an example of the user creation portion in a function, lemme know and I'll toss it in an edit.